# How do I get FlashDevelop to show the right api documentation?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flashdevelop, flixel

I have been working with Flixel in FlashDevelop for quite some time, and I recently updated my Flixel library to the latest version. Some things have changed names or have been moved or had their inputs changed. For some reason, FlashDevelop is still showing me the documentation from the old version of Flixel as I type things in, so I keep trying to use variable and functions etc that no longer exist.

I've searched around for a solution, and I'm sure it will be painfully easy/obvious once I get it fixed, but so far I've had no luck finding one.

And I also wonder if I'm calling it the wrong thing (which might be why I can't find the solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlashDevelop shows the documentation as extracted from the libraries you have included in your project, is it possible you have both the old and the new versions added to your project?

Comment: I just tried tracking down to see if there was maybe some bogus entries in the Flixel library...and the functions and variables that were showing up wrong before I opened the files are now giving me the correct doc text. Is it possible that FlashDevelop had the old version's documentation cached, and opening the files made it load the documentation anew?